# UploadFile prevent page postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

My project is a Asp.Net project. The code is written in vb.net.
There are file-upload and a gridview with this TemplatesField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <a onserverclick="fnEditWork" class="AEditWork" href='<%#Eval("WorkID")' runat="server" id="EditWork"></a>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

in this situation the file-upload works but the anchor does not fire post-back. (the 'fnEditWork' function on onserverclick does not fire.) But when I comment the file-upload code out then fnEditWork function fires.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with AJAX.
Put something like that arround it

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                   <ContentTemplate>

                   </ContentTemplate>
                   <Triggers>
                      <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlID="AEditWork" EventName="onserverclick" />
                   </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```